# Conceptual advice on proximity analyses in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, proximity

I have a question concerning proximity analyses in `arcpy` (ArcGIS 10.7). Forgive me if it takes a while to explain, but I've added a figure below to illustrate my problem.

### Explanation

I'm trying to discover potential lakes (i.e. exposed subglacial overdeepenings) in the ice-free beds of ~1000 glaciers. I have the locations of all overdeepenings and the position of the glacier front at several points in time. So far, I have

- created a line perpendicular to the flowline of the glacier
- clipped the whole glacier shp with that line to get the ice-free bedrock
- clipped the shp containing all the overdeepenings with that bedrock shp giving me all ice-free lakes

All of that works fine as long as the glacier runs in a more or less straight line. If it bends back on itself, I get problems as some parts of the upstream glacier are wrongly considered ice-free and lakes are incorrectly found (red circles in the figure below).

So far, different approaches to solve this have not worked:

- I thought of trying to clip the glacier just along its main glacier bed to exclude all upper parts. However, sometimes the upper parts of the glacier converge at mountain ridges with the ends of lower tributary glacier arms.
  This means, my polygon is at these points not easily separated into lower and upper parts because of the missing polygon separation (orange area in the figure). So, I think I have to use this 'endless' perpendicular line to clip the whole thing.
- I have done `Near` analyses with different points along the upper flowline. I was hoping that some of them would be closer to my incorrect lakes than the point at the true glacier front. This way, I could have determined that the lakes were further upstream.
  Unfortunately, this does not always work. In the figure, the point at the glacier front (A) is still closer to the wrong lakes than point B or C. And as the upper flowline consists of nearly 600 points, I want to avoid doing a near analysis for every point hoping that one will be closer.

[image]

### Now the question

I'm looking for advice on how to solve this issue. Is there a way using `arcpy` or Python in general to exclude all sinks upstream from the glacier front?

Maybe a better way to separate the glacier in upper and lower parts?

Or another proximity analysis?

Comment: Find chainage of lake centers on the line. Might work direction of flow line is correct.

Comment: Shapes of individual glaciers are wrong anyway...

Comment: Unfortunately, I just have the main flowline. Any lakes in tributary valleys or larger cirque areas at the top (as the wrong lakes in my example) don't lie close enough to the flowline.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'Shapes of individual glaciers are wrong anyway'? The shapes are from the Randolph Glacier Inventory and relatively exact, at least they are fully sufficient for what I'm trying here.

Comment: If I correctly understand "exposed bed", your single glacier is now a set of multiple glaciers. Small ones used to be a tributaries of a bigger.

Comment: Project your lakes on a black bold line shown, it might help to understand my 1st comment.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However, and I'm so sorry, maybe my English is too bad, but I still do not understand what you mean. "Exposed glacier bed" means the glacier is gone, up to the point at the glacier front. Higher up, the glacier would still be there. 
And what does your last comment mean? Some lakes are not close to the main flowline, how could I connect them? Could you please elaborate a bit? Thanks!

Comment: Run NEAR between lakes and line with location checked. Add XY event to display to see 'connection' points.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that still does not help me, sadly. I still cannot distinguish between lakes that lie in the lower or the upper part. Some of the "upper lakes" are closer to the flowline of the lower part than to the flowline of the upper part. I guess, I have to try another workflow altogether...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, the use of a DEM can solve this problem:
If the location of the glacier front is known, so is the altitude. It then can be assumed that all subglacial overdeepenings below that altitude have been exposed.

While this does not use proximity analyses, it should solve the problem in nearly all cases.